# how to use lambdaj with hamcrest matcher (hasItemsInArray) for filtering a list

Tags: java, predicate, hamcrest, lambdaj, matcher

I'm trying to filter a list of caroffers Objects which are found in vendor array through lambdaj. But the below code doesn't work. I'm getting empty list.

```
    String[] vendor = {"FORD","TOYOTA"}; 
    List carsOffers=filter(having(on(CarProviderModel.class).getProviderName(),  hasItemInArray(vendor)),carprvds);
```

where as the below code works. Only equalTo seems to work for me.

```
    List carsOffers=filter(having(on(CarProviderModel.class).getProviderName(),  anyOf(equalTo(vendor[0]), equalTo(vendor[1]))),carprvds);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `isIn`:

```
filter(having(on(CarProviderModel.class).getProviderName(), 
    isIn(vendor)),carprvds);
```

`hasItemInArray` kind of does the opposite of what you want - instead of filtering on items where `getProviderName()` is one of a supplied list of `vendor`, it's filtering on items where `vendor` is one of the items returned by `getProviderName()` - of course  `getProviderName()` (presumably!) doesn't return an array, so you get no matches.

The [Hamcrest `Matchers` class documentation](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) gives examples of both:

**isIn**:

```
assertThat("foo", isIn(Arrays.asList("bar", "foo")))
```

**hasItemInArray**:

```
assertThat(new String[] {"foo", "bar"}, hasItemInArray(startsWith("ba")))
```

(N.B. Note that your code was calling the other overload of `hasItemInArray`, which is equivalent to `hasItemInArray(equalTo(vendor))` - this may make it clearer to you that you were testing for equality with your `vendor` collection).